# Probability of the sum of exponentials being greater than a number

Tags: probability

Say we have Xi ~ Exponential(1/3)
We add Xi (all independent variables) until we reach a value of 5 or greater than 5
What is the probability of the sum of Xi being greater than 7?

I have no idea how to resolve this problem, all i can tell is that the sum of N variables of exponential(1/3) distribution is a gamma(N,1/3)

however when if i try to calculete P(gamma(n,1/3) > 7) the answer depends on N, and i cant find a way aroud this.

Thanks.

Comment: Presumably your $1/5$ should be $1/3$, or else your $1/3$ should be $1/5$.

Comment: ... and your $X_i$ must be assumed to be independent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider a Poisson process, where $X_i$ is the waiting time for the $i$'th occurrence.  Then you're looking for the probability that there is no occurrence in a certain interval.

Comment: I still dont get it, if Xi is the waiting time for the i'th ocurrence then Xi ~ Gamma (i,1/3), to find P(Xi>7) i have the same issue as before, i dont know the value of i.

Comment: As for the probability that there is no occurence in the interval (5,7) i dont know how to calculate it because of the same reasons (dont know i)

Comment: The number of occurrences of a Poisson process of rate $r$ in an interval of length $L$ is a Poisson random variable with parameter $rL$.

Comment: Thanks for your help Robert, now i get it, i should calculate the probability of a Poisson((7-5)*1/3) being equal to 0.